# Python parse txt file, PEST output, jacobian.txt

Tags: python, parsing

We are stuck trying to find a way to parse a tricky text file that is produced by a PEST analysis using Python. It shows measurements of 63 different variables for over 30,000 observations. Here's an example of the output (3/>30,000 shown)

```
                           cmfa          cmfb          cmfc          cmfd          cmla          cmlb          cmlc          cmld
                           cmle          cgfa          cgfb          cgfc          cgfd          cgfe          dgfa          dgfb
                           dgfc          dgfd          icfa          icfb          icfc          icfd          vawa          vawb
                           vawc          vawd          vawe          vawf          vswa          vswb          vswc          vswd
                           vswe          chfa          chfb          chfc          chfd          chfe          cgwa          cgwb
                           cgwc          cgwd          cgwe          crta          crtb          crtc          crtd          crte
                           icha          ichb          ichc          ichd          iche          csea          cseb          csec
                           csed          csee          csef          caqa          caqb          crsa          crsb

                0   -1.900000E-03  1.080000E-02  3.150000E-02   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -3.020000E-02
                      0.00000     -1.870000E-02   0.00000      4.600000E-03   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000      4.510000E-02
                      0.00000       0.00000      3.650000E-02 -7.000000E-03 -2.100000E-03 -2.000000E-04  3.200000E-03  8.000000E-03
                    -7.000000E-04 -1.500000E-02   0.00000      4.800000E-03  1.900000E-03  4.000000E-04  2.500000E-03  2.500000E-03
                    -1.400000E-02   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -3.200000E-03 -8.060000E-02
                    -0.126500      0.298400       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000      8.000000E-04
                    -1.900000E-03  1.400000E-03   0.00000       0.00000     -3.200000E-03   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000    
                      0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -1.200000E-02  1.930000E-02

                1   -1.800000E-03  1.140000E-02  1.850000E-02   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -2.600000E-02
                      0.00000     -8.200000E-03   0.00000      1.200000E-03   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000    
                      0.00000       0.00000      2.560000E-02 -6.100000E-03 -1.100000E-03   0.00000      3.000000E-03  7.400000E-03
                    -7.000000E-04 -1.410000E-02   0.00000      5.000000E-03  1.900000E-03  3.000000E-04  2.300000E-03  2.300000E-03
                    -1.330000E-02   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -3.400000E-03 -8.410000E-02
                    -0.123500      0.301900       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000      1.200000E-03
                    -2.000000E-03  1.400000E-03   0.00000       0.00000     -3.200000E-03   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000    
                      0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -1.280000E-02  2.050000E-02

                2   -3.300000E-03  6.500000E-03  4.040000E-02   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -7.060000E-02
                     4.840000E-02 -0.112500      0.110300       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       1.10330       0.00000    
                      0.00000       0.00000      3.940000E-02 -8.500000E-03 -1.120000E-02  6.600000E-03  5.700000E-03  1.430000E-02
                    -1.300000E-03 -2.470000E-02   0.00000      3.700000E-03  2.200000E-03  5.000000E-04  4.300000E-03  4.500000E-03
                    -2.250000E-02   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -2.000000E-03 -5.840000E-02
                    -0.157300      0.292400       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -3.600000E-03
                    -1.700000E-03  1.200000E-03   0.00000       0.00000     -3.400000E-03   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000    
                      0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -7.400000E-03  1.180000E-02

                3   -2.200000E-03  1.040000E-02  3.500000E-02   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -4.390000E-02
                      0.00000     -3.170000E-02  2.590000E-02   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000      0.259400       0.00000    
                      0.00000       0.00000      3.920000E-02 -1.030000E-02 -3.500000E-03  1.500000E-03  3.600000E-03  9.000000E-03
                    -9.000000E-04 -1.680000E-02   0.00000      4.700000E-03  2.000000E-03  3.000000E-04  2.700000E-03  2.800000E-03
                    -1.560000E-02   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -3.200000E-03 -7.920000E-02
                    -0.131600      0.302200       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000      3.000000E-04
                    -2.000000E-03  1.300000E-03   0.00000       0.00000     -3.300000E-03   0.00000       0.00000       0.00000    
                      0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000     -1.180000E-02  1.880000E-02
```

The letter codes (cmfa, cmfb, etc.) are the names of the 63 variables. Each of the letter-code variables relate to the number in the same position for each of the following text blocks.

The first block of numbers is for observation 0, the next block for observation 1 and so on for more than 30,000 observations.

We want to find a way to turn this into a text file (preferably .csv). In the case of my text example, it would have 63 columns and 3 rows (+1 for identifier). Each column would be titled with the appropriate letter code (cmfa, etc)

If possible, we would like this to run on a file with any number of columns and any number of observations

Comment: What did you try so far? A simple solution: You could use a textprocessor with regular expressions, like vi (unix) or notepad++ (win) and replace single newlines into blanks or tabs, than replace blanks or tabs by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to parse the file that you have provided(independent of number of rows in file) using simple python, better implementations can be done using regular expressions but i would leave it for you to try further:

```
#Importing required libraries
import numpy as np
import csv

#Open input file
with open('input.txt','rb') as f:
    line = f.read().splitlines()

#Read file and do some parsing
line2 = []
for l in line:
    z = l.split(" ")
    l2 = []
    for val in z:
        if not(val==''):
            l2.append(val)
    if len(l2)==9:
        line2.append(l2[1:9])
    elif len(l2)==7 or len(l2)==8:
        line2.append(l2)

#Remove unnecessary rows and do type conversion to float
pl = np.arange(0,len(line2)+1,8)
line3 = []
for i in np.arange(0,len(pl)-1):
    z = line2[pl[i]:pl[i+1]]
    z2 = [item for sublist in z for item in sublist]
    if i==0:
        line3.append(z2)
    else:
        line3.append([float(i) for i in z2])

#Write to output file
with open('output.csv','wb') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for row in line3:
        wr.writerow(row)
```

In case you want to keep the indexes:

```
#Importing required libraries
import numpy as np
import csv

#Open input file
with open('input.txt','rb') as f:
    line = f.read().splitlines()

#Read file and do some parsing
line2 = []
for l in line:
    z = l.split(" ")
    l2 = []
    for val in z:
        if not(val==''):
            l2.append(val)
    if not(len(l2)==0):
        line2.append(l2)

#Remove unnecessary rows and do type conversion to float
pl = np.arange(0,len(line2)+1,8)
line3 = []
for i in np.arange(0,len(pl)-1):
    if i==0:
        z = line2[pl[i]:pl[i+1]]
        z2 = [item for sublist in z for item in sublist]
        line3.append(['']+z2)
    else:
        z = line2[pl[i]:pl[i+1]]
        z2 = [item for sublist in z for item in sublist]
        line3.append([float(i) for i in z2])

#Write to output file
with open('output.csv','wb') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for row in line3:
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you Gaurav! This does exactly what I had asked for. I forgot to ask whether the observation number could be transcribed as well (in this case 0,1,2,3) as the first column in the csv. Would it be possible to have that in the csv as well?

Comment: Edited with obs number included. Cheers!! Please mark as correct if you think this is ok.

Comment: Again, you answered exactly what I asked. My mistake, I forgot to ask if it is also possible to name the new ID field as 'ID' or 'FID' or something like that

Comment: Change this line (line3.append(['']+z2)) to (line3.append(['ID']+z2))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `mmap` and a regex to parse the file without having to read in the entire file into memory.

Something like:

```
import re
import mmap
import os

size=os.stat(fn_in).st_size

with open(fn_in, "r") as fin, open(fn_out, "w") as fout:
    data = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), size, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    for idx, m in enumerate(re.finditer(r"(.*?)(?:(?:^\s*$)|\Z)", data, re.M | re.S)):
        block=m.group(0).strip()
        if not block:
            continue
        if idx==0:
            fout.write("O_N,"+",".join(block.split())+"\n")
        else:
            fout.write(",".join(block.split())+"\n")
```